# Is there a way for a rules execute PHP action to return a value?

Tags: rules

I would like to be able to stuff the result of the PHP code into a rules variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's not possible. More info here: http://drupal.org/node/1415628

Answer (score 1):

For achieve this you can save your result in some where(**(variable, session,static variable etc**) and in anotherside use your variable, 
if you return value is array or object just need [serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it and in anotherway [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it.

maybe this code take some idea to you
in rules in php execution

```
 global $user;
 $myreturn=array (....);
variable_set('return-'.$user->uid,serialize($myreturn));
```

and in another part

```
 global $user;
 $yourvariable=unserialize(variable_get('return-'.$user->uid));
```

**This is just trickly way and maybe another solution be better for achieve this question**

Comment: I am talking about the [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module. The "other part" isn't PHP.

Comment: @Gaelan can you tell me where is other part?

Comment: The other part is configuration in the Rules module.

Comment: @Gaelan ,If there you can't use php how do you want use returned values?

Comment: I want to access the returned value from the rule that called the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

For text, you can use the Add a Variable action and then set the value to use php evaluation.